# Using a self-signed certificate for a REST API on a remote system

Tags: rest, ssl

I've done a good amount of digging into this, and it looks like a self-signed certificate is the way to go in my situation. But I want to make sure I fully understand the ramifications of what I plan to do.

Basically, I have a website that will serve up content that lives in a MongoDB database. The website itself already has an SSL certificate issued by my hosting service, so that part is all good.

However, the database itself lives on a remote Linux VM, in a cloud hosting service. That VM hosts the REST API (a Spring Boot application) that the website communicates with in order to serve up the content.

Only I have the authority to manage and edit the content. No other users will be able to log into the website to edit the content. This is done through the website, though, so any communication with the REST API on the remote Linux VM (namely, for authentication) should ideally be encrypted.

So I need an SSL certificate for the Linux VM. The problem is, the remote Linux VM that hosts the REST API is not part of my website's domain and has its own IP address. No certificate authority is going to generate a certificate for a bare IP address; it requires a domain. That just leaves the self-signing certificate option, unless I somehow create a new domain for the VM, which I'm not sure I want to do.

Since I'm the only one who will be using the REST API to modify and maintain the content (all other requests are read-only for the website itself and don't require authentication), is there really an issue with using a self-signed SSL certificate for this? I would have to tell my application to trust it, but other than that, are there any ramifications, or alternate routes that I should be pursuing?

Comment: There is a risk that a hacker could fool your application into getting its data from the wrong place. You can mitigate that risk with simple [certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). The more complicated option would be to issue yourself a self-signed root CA certificate and install it on both machines as a trusted authority, then issue your certificates from that chain of trust.

Comment: I like the idea of certificate pinning, especially since the website just issues CURL requests with PHP. Since PHP added the `CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY` option, this seems like it'd be pretty easy to do. Thanks for the advice.